# No module named 'cv2' even though it was successfully installed

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I pip installed several packages (opencv, face_recognition, imutils)
They were all successfully installed, but are not recognized
I have a python script named script.py which imports cv2, but when I run it I get the following:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

I tried using pip list command to see the packages I have installed, but the packages I installed are not showing as you can see below.
[image]
I run pythonVersion.py to check my python version, it says it's using 3.8.2 which is where my packages are stored, as shown below.
[image]

I tried using #!/Users/Khuzama/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8 (the path of my packages) in my script, but still the same issue.

I am using jupyter notebook (anaconda navigator)

Comment: If you install packages from inside a notebook using `%pip install PACKAGE` line magic then the package will be installed into the Python environment associated with the kernel the current notebook is running against,

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably the python environment you installed the packages are not the one you are currently referring to.

Try seeing the output of

```
which python
```

if this doesn't point to the anaconda one, then navigate to Users/Khuzama/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8 and run your script from there. Alternatively you can link the python from anaconda as the main python for your system

Comment: Output of which python3 is /usr/bin/python3, how do I make it point to the anaconda one?

Comment: This actually suggests you are running on a different python, compared to the one you have just installed.

Can you do this:

conda activate

Comment: So I did what you suggested, and now which python points to /opt/anaconda3/bin/python.  But it still doesn't solve the issue because I need it to point to the exact path i.e. opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8

Comment: Simply point the python to the version you want to. This should solve your problem.